# Reference request: Leonardo Da Vinci's supposed math results

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

Many reputable sources (I can give as many as you want) describe Da Vinci as a mathematician, but they never mention a single theorem, result, or lemma that he proved. There's the golden ratio spiral, but that's ad hoc nonsense and certainly not what all the writers were thinking of. He used perspective in drawings, but that was already used and hardly counts anyways. Thus I'm wondering whether anyone here happens to know if he actually proved anything. I suspect not, but I'd be arguing against dozens of writers, journalists, and historians and it's impossible to prove a negative.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fermat never really proved very much in the way of theorem, result, or lemma either, as far as we’re aware (key word: proof). What constituted a “proof”, “mathematician” or even “mathematics” in the 1400s is vastly different from in the 2000s.

Comment: I think the term "mathematician" is used more generally than you suppose.  A math enthusiast that spends an enormous amount of time learning, using, and appreciating pre-existing mathematics is still a mathematician in most peoples' eyes.  Mandelbrot did not prove much (as far as I know) but he's still called a mathematician. In that regard, I think Da Vinci qualifies.

Comment: I suppose I am saying "mathematician" and "mathematics researcher" are not exactly synonymous.

Comment: @NeilStrickland my thought exactly! It is also more likely that a meaningful answer will emerge there, I think.

Comment: A graphical [proof](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pythagoras_theorem_leonardo_da_vinci.png) of Pythagoras' theorem attributed to Leonardo da Vinci has been debunked by [Franz Lemmermeyer](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.47.5.361)

Comment: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Leonardo/ says, "He gave several methods of squaring the circle, again using mechanical methods." Does that count?

Comment: The fact that $C_n$ and $D_n$ are the only finite subgroups of $O(2)$ is often attributed to da Vinci.

Comment: Can you supply your sources? Wikipedia calls Leonardo a "polymath", not "mathematician".

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon Often? What did he actually prove? AFAIK the abstract notion (and word) "group" is due to Galois 300 years after Leonardo's death. Of course "symmetry" was thousands of years older...

Comment: I found the following article by Francesco Severi (I don't know if he is the same person as the italian algebraic geometer) https://www.jstor.org/stable/29758044. At least he give details of Da Vinci's "mathematical work", so it may be relevant to your question.

Comment: @efs yes, he is. [He also wrote a book on him](https://www.worldcat.org/en/search?q=ti%3ALeonardo+AND+au%3AFrancesco+Severi+) ("unfortunately" in Italian) and some contributions published in collections, proceedings and journals. I think this material is relevant, but I have not consulted it so I am not completely sure.

Comment: Luca Pacioli and Piero della Francesca are usually cited as renaissance artists who were also mathematicians (Piero found an astonishing formula for the volume of the tetrahedron). The only thing I know about Leonardo is that he has drawn various beautiful polyhedra in the famous book of Pacioli "De divina proportione".

(Imagine that you write a maths paper and Leonardo offers to draw the pictures...)

Answer (score 10):

I follow up on Dustin Mixon's comment.

Hermann Weyl, in his 1952 book [Symmetry](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/mathe320_2017/blog17/Hermann_Weyl_Symmetry.pdf) (page 66), argues that Leonardo classified the only possible central symmetries in two dimensions, now referred to as the cyclic group $C_n$ and the dihedral group $D_n$.

> Leonardo da Vinci engaged in systematically determining the possible
> symmetries of a central building and how to attach chapels and niches
> without destroying the symmetry of the nucleus. In abstract modern
> terminology, his result is essentially our table of the possible
> finite groups of rotations (proper and improper) in two dimensions.

For a further discussion, see [The Octagon in Leonardo’s Drawings](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00004-007-0056-8.pdf), by Mark Reynolds.

To call this [Leonardo's theorem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Leonardo) is a stretch, since Leonardo did not actually formulate this classification as a theorem, at best it is implicit in his [drawings.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Leonardo_da_vinci%2C_Institut_de_France%2C_Manoscritto_B%2C_c._95r.jpg/440px-Leonardo_da_vinci%2C_Institut_de_France%2C_Manoscritto_B%2C_c._95r.jpg)